How to ignore some dependencies if current version match a pattern with Renovate?
I am using the Mend-hosted GitHub Renovate App and I push these two files to the remote repository on GitHub for renovate to parse through the package.json.
I want Renovate to ignore all chalk versions, that end with "java", and not create a PR.
There is an exact example of it in the docs here, that is apparently supposed to work, but it isn't for me and I am getting a PR with the name "Update dependency chalk to v5" and change 2.5.0-java -> 5.3.0.
What is the reason?
package.json:
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "chalk": "2.5.0-java"
  }
}

renovate.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackageNames": ["chalk"],
      "allowedVersions": "!/java$/"
    }
  ]
}


5.3.0 is a valid version according to your config since it does not end with java. The config doesn't state which packages are eligible for a PR but rather which PR are eligible to be proposed. I'm not sure what's your goal here. If you don't want any upgrade for chalk you can use a rule without the allowedVersions at all but rather disable any upgrade (I don't remember the config right now).

So 'allowedVersions' only checks for the version in the remote repository. My goal is to disable the PR, if the version in package.json ends in "java". It shouldn't throw an error saying the version is 'undefined'.

Okay, sounds like you want matchCurrentVersion. If it helps, I can make it a proper answer. I've never used it.

Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! I will mention you in the answer.

As @Gaël J suggested, the more appropriate option is to use matchCurrentVersion.
renovate.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:recommended"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackageNames": ["chalk"],
      "matchCurrentVersion": "/java$/"
      "enabled": false
    }
  ]
}

This now disables the check and subsequently disables the generation of the PR. Logs:
"deps": [
  {
    "depType": "devDependencies",
    "depName": "chalk",
    "currentValue": "2.5.2-java",
    "datasource": "npm",
    "prettyDepType": "devDependency",
    "updates": [],
    "packageName": "chalk",
    "skipReason": "disabled"
  }
],

